# Hazelcast 3.4 as second level cache provider

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, hazelcast, provider

I want to configure my **hazelcast as second level cache provider** for hibernate's second level cache.**Currently i am using ehcache as cache provider**.

I want to replace this because hazelcast is a distributed cache.
Can any one tell me the steps to configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/hibernate-2ndlevel-cache

This is nice example for how to use hibernate 2nd level cache with hazelcast. Also if you encounter another problem you can ask https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hazelcast or in stackoverflow.

Also hazelcast provides nice documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#hibernate-second-level-cache

Comment: I have done all the configurations.But i want to test it in my application.How can i test it.For eg:- i have an entity Country
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
class country{
}

Comment: Do you want to write unit test for your application? Eg. whether cache is  working or not.

Comment: Yes,kind of unit testing.
Here is one more issue.When i upgrade my hazelcast version from 3.1.7 to 3.4 ,i got exception 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.util.QueryResultSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
while casting Collection<Category> collection to List<Category>)collection.
Here collection is categoriesCache.values() where categoriesCache is my IMap<Long, Category> categoriesCache;
Do you know the reason as this happened after upgrading of hazelcast from 3.1.7 to 3.4

Comment: We changed the internal response object in 3.3 I guess. The new QueryResultSet is more efficient in (de-)serialization but as the name mentions it is a Set now not a List anymore. So either change your code to use a Collection or Set.

Comment: thankyou very much @noctarius.I was using Collection.sort() method.I was casting QueryResultSet to List as it requires List to sort.So i have to make a List from QueryResultSet and have to use it in Collection.sort().Am i right?

Comment: One more thing i want to know.I have replaced ehcache with hazelcast as cache provider for hibernate 2nd level cache.I had a file ehcache.xml in which i defined the regions, ttl time etc for my queryCache .Now as i have removed ehcache.xml, i dont know where i should define these configurations for hazelcast to use queryCache.Please suggest me.